# Mysql triggers : OLD and NEW how to serialize as string ？

Tags: mysql

1. I want to implement, when updating the data in the table, use MySQL trigger to convert all the fields before the update of the row record and all the updated fields into strings and store them in another table.
2. My current practice is to use the CONCAT function to stitch the fields together, but if I have a lot of tables, or if there are many fields in the table, it is quite troublesome.
3. Is there any way for MySQL to serialize OLD and NEW into a string and then insert it into a field in the table?

Here is mine tables and trigger define:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_name`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_name` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'name ID',
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'name',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_audit_log`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_audit_log` (
  `id` INT (10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'audit ID',
  `action` VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'tbl_name action',
  `old_row_value` LONGTEXT COMMENT 'old row data value',
  `new_row_value` LONGTEXT COMMENT 'new row data value',
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'action time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `audit_name_update`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `audit_name_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `tbl_name` FOR EACH ROW # After Update trigger
  BEGIN
    DECLARE k_old_value VARCHAR (4000) ; 
    DECLARE k_new_value VARCHAR (4000) ;
    SET k_old_value = CONCAT( '(', old.`id`, ',', old.`name`, ')' ) ;
    SET k_new_value = CONCAT( '(', new.`id`, ',', new.`name`, ')' ) ; 
    INSERT INTO `tbl_audit_log` ( `action`, `old_row_value`, `new_row_value`, `time` )
    VALUES ( 'update', k_old_value, k_new_value, NOW() ) ;
  END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by: " serialize OLD and NEW into a string" ? Please elaborate further.

Comment: 1. For example, I have a table t_order(id, order_num, amount, username, order_time) and an audit table t_audit_log(id, action, old_row_data_value, new_row_data_value, time);
2. When the data of the t_order row is updated, the data before the update of the row and the updated data need to be inserted into t_audit_log.old_row_data_value and t_audit_log.new_row_data_value.
3. Now I can only get the row data with CONCAT function through new.clounm ONE BY ONE rather than get the whole row data through new.* or ROW(NEW.*).
4. So if there is a function, that can simply get all the data of NEW.

Comment: You can see that I use SET k_new_value = CONCAT( '(', new.`id`, ',', new.`name`, ')' ) ;  to get the row data string, but it is too troublesome if the table have many fields. So I look for if there is a simple way.

Comment: no there is no simple way. You will have to refer every column with its name individually